# VF Controller - ForEach error and query issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Ok, for some reason the dev console keeps throwing this error when I add the for each statement: "expecting right curly bracket, found 'for'"

If I exclude that statement, then I get an error on my TeamMembers query that says "unexpected token '=' "

Any help?

Here is my class

```
public class LicensingGridController {

    public class TeamMemberStats{

        list<Account_Counselor__c> TeamMembers = new list<Account_Counselor__c>();

        Account a = [Select Id, Name 
                     FROM Account 
                     WHERE Name = 'The Acorn Tree'];

        list<BCS__c>Hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__c
                            FROM BCS__c
                            WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE];

        for(BCS__c b:Hubs){
            TeamMembers = [Select Id,Name 
                           FROM Account_Counselor__c 
                           WHERE Hub_Name__c = :b.Id];
        }

        public List<BCS__c> getHubs(){
            return Hubs;
        }

        public List<Account_Counselor__c> getTeamMembers(){
            return TeamMembers;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: You need to have that code inside a method or constructor.

Comment: My 2 cents: I think you should use an IDE to write codes rather then developer console.Apart from all the benefits they provide, sometime it is easier to track such errors in an IDE then Developer console.

Comment: And make sure when you move to a method per@KeithC, remove the query from a loop as its a best practice to not have queries in loops.           {List<Id> newList = new List<Id>();
for(BCS__c bcs:Hubs){

newList.add(bcd.Id);

}
TeamMembers = [Select Id,Name 
                           FROM Account_Counselor__c 
                           WHERE Hub_Name__c IN :newList];}